# How to search for a pattern having the special characters in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have to match file1 with file2 line by line . But file1 is in below format .If am using ak command to search with the below line in file2 , its throwing error with syntax error at '=' .

File1 :

```
Country_code=US/base_div_nbr=18/retail_channel_code=1/visit_date=2010-01-02/load_time_stamp=20100102058100
Country_code=US/base_div_nbr=18/retail_channel_code=1/visit_date=2010-01-02/load_time_stamp=20100102091000
Country_code=US/base_div_nbr=18/retail_channel_code=1/visit_date=2010-01-02/load_time_stamp=20100102067000
```

File2:

```
Country_code=US/base_div_nbr=18/retail_channel_code=1/visit_date=2010-01-02/load_time_stamp=20100102058100
Country_code=US/base_div_nbr=18/retail_channel_code=1/visit_date=2010-01-02/load_time_stamp=20100102091000
```

I took total line from file1 as the search pattern to search in file2 using below command:

```
awk "/$line/ {print ;}" file2
```

Here file1 , 3 rd record not found in file2 , So I need to know these differences

I am very much new to shell scripting, So please suggest me on this.

Comment: Why don't you just do `grep -vf f2 f1`?

Comment: Do you want to get the lines that are common in both files?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us  what you've done. How are you reading the files? Where is `$line` defined? What is the exact error you get?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a job for `comm`, assuming you can sort both input files, but if you want to use awk something like this might do it depending on your unstated requirements:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {file1[NR]=$0; next} $0 != file1[FNR]' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to print the lines that are common to both files. In that case, `awk` is really not the best tool. You could instead do one of

```
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

or

```
grep -Fxf file1 file2
```

If you really want to do it with `awk`, you could try

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]; next} $0 in a' file1 file2
```